# Passing pointer on pointers into function

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Couldn't find answer to this. When I have pointer on pointers

```
char **buffer;
```

and I want to pass it to a function

```
void some_func(char **buffer) {}
```

so after this function call buffer will contain data from this function how should I call this function please ?

Comment: Depending on the function, it may be simpler or less confusing to return a new pointer - making the function `char **func(char **)`.

Comment: If you only want to modify the contents of `buffer`, and not the pointer itself, you can call: `some_func(buffer);`

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. Will `buffer` contain anything when you first call the function?

Comment: You cannot change `buffer` of the caller from inside the function. C is strictly pass-by-value. If you mean `*buffer`, it is not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your example it is correct but the fact is that you are passing this pointer to pointer by value so pass it by pointer:

```
// initialize it 
char** buffer;

void some_func(char ***buffer) {} // by reference
```

and in function call:

```
 some_funct(&buffer);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
some_func(&buffer);
```

That's the call you need.

And the function should be...

```
void some_func(char ***buffer) {}
```

To manipulate buffer...

```
*buffer = something;
```